# Unityで2DのキャラクターにAddForceでジャンプさせようとしてもジャンプしない時がある

Tags: c#, unity3d

Unityで2Dのキャラクターに左右移動を矢印キー、ジャンプをスペースキーの入力のタイミングでさせようとしています。
ジャンプの命令にはRigidbody2DのAddForceを使っています。
どういうタイミングか分からないのですが、かなりの確率でジャンプしない時があります。
ジャンプ命令の後に効果音を再生するようにしているのですが、音はジャンプしてもしなくても出るのでスペースキーの入力が拾えていないというわけではないようです。
スペースキーを押したら必ずジャンプするようにはどうしたらいいですか。

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour{
    [SerializeField] float moveSpeed = 3.5f;
    [SerializeField] float jumpPower = 150f;
    [SerializeField] float jumpAngle = 60f;
    public LayerMask layerBlock;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //←キー　→キーで移動
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"),0).normalized*moveSpeed;

        if (rb.velocity != Vector2.zero)
        {
            if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") != 0)
            {
                if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0)   //右向き画像
                {
                    transform.localScale = new Vector2(1f, 1f);
                }
                else   //左向き画像
                {
                    transform.localScale = new Vector2(-1f, 1f);
                }
            }
        }
        //ブロックに接地している時にスペースキーを押されたらジャンプ
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {   
            if (Physics2D.CircleCast(transform.position, 0.35f, transform.up * -1f, 0.15f, layerBlock))
            {
                Jump();
            }
        }     
    }
    private void Jump()
    {
        float rad = jumpAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad;// 角度をラジアンに変換  
        Vector3 direction;

        if (transform.localScale.x>0)
        {
            direction = new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(rad) , Mathf.Sin(rad), 0);
        }
        else
        {
            direction = new Vector3(-Mathf.Cos(rad) , Mathf.Sin(rad) , 0);
        }
        //ジャンプ
        rb.AddForce(direction * jumpPower, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        GetComponent<Sound>().SoundJump();   //ジャンプ効果音
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

試してみないとわかりませんが、`Update` ではなく、`FixedUpdate` で処理すればいいんじゃないでしょうか。
ただし、今度は `Input.GetKeyDown` が正しく動かなくなるので、自分でトリガー処理をしなければなりません。

```cs
    bool lastSpaceDown = false;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //←キー　→キーで移動
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"),0).normalized*moveSpeed;

        if (rb.velocity != Vector2.zero)
        {
            if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") != 0)
            {
                if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0)   //右向き画像
                {
                    transform.localScale = new Vector2(1f, 1f);
                }
                else   //左向き画像
                {
                    transform.localScale = new Vector2(-1f, 1f);
                }
            }
        }
        //ブロックに接地している時にスペースキーを押されたらジャンプ
        bool spaceDown = Input.GetKey(Keycode.Space);
        if (! lastSpaceDown && spaceDown)
        {   
            if (Physics2D.CircleCast(transform.position, 0.35f, transform.up * -1f, 0.15f, layerBlock))
            {
                Jump();
            }
        }     
        lastSpaceDown = spaceDown;
    }
```

https://qiita.com/yuji_yasuhara/items/6f50ecdd5d59e83aac99

上記のサイトでは `AddForce(ForceMode.Impulse` は `Update` で呼んで大丈夫、と書いてあるけど、問題は `velocity` に値を代入している点ではないかと。

例えば、`Update` → `Update` → `FixedUpdate` (及び物理演算) という流れで処理が進むことがあったとして、一回目の `Update` でジャンプ判定が行われた場合、二回目の `Update` で `velocity` に代入することによって、一回目の `Update` の `AddForce` で加えた力が消されてしまうのではないかな、という気がします。
まぁあくまで気がするだけなのですが、いずれにせよ詳しく物理処理を理解しないうちは、「`Rigidbody` の移動処理は、とりあえず `FixedUpdate` でしておけ」と考えておくのが無難な気がします。

Comment: イメージ通りの動作を確認しました。丁寧な説明ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

rb.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"),0).normalized*moveSpeed;
を問答無用で毎フレーム実行していますので、
仮にジャンプして上下方向の速度を得ても、次のフレームでは上下方向の速度が0にされていそうです。

Comment: Update()の中をif(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){ //ブロックに接地していたらジャンプ}else{//←キー　→キーで移動}に変更してみましたが同じでした

Comment: その場合でも、スペースキーを押した次のフレームでやっぱり上下方向の速度が0にされていそうです。y方向の速度を保持するとどうなりますか。つまり、0ではなく、rb.velocity.y

Comment: rb.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"),rb.velocity.y)に変えてみたらジャンプしない割合は減ったような気がしますが、ジャンプしない時もあります。ジャンプしなかった後もう一度スペースキーを押すとジャンプの高さが高くなったりしてコントロールできてない感は否めません。